# Flask routes with path parameter / sub-path causing issues with referenced assets

Tags: python, html, flask, url, routes

I have a flask web application where I'm using a variety of themify icons etc in my html pages, for example:

```
<i class="c-indigo-500 ti-search"></i>
```

For a standard flask route like:

```
@app.route("/orders")
def route():
return render_template("page.html")
```

Everything works fine. My icons, special fonts etc all render fine on the HTML page.

[image]

However, if I try to include a route with a sub-path or a path parameter, e.g.

```
@app.route("/orders/<orderid>")
def route(orderid):
return render_template("page.html")
```

Suddenly the references on the HTML page seem to break. Icons do not render, e.g.

[image]

I think the clue is in looking at the developer console, I can see that the path for assets seems to be incorrect? e.g.

```
GET http://localhost:5000/ordersearch/static/assets/fonts/e23a7dcaefbde4e74e263247aa42ecd7.ttf net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (NOT FOUND)
```

The problem being that the path has `/ordersearch/` in it now. Without that section, the path would be correct. What am I doing wrong here? How can I have path parameters or sub-paths in flask (e.g. /search/documents/document/) without breaking the references to assets? My folder structure is as follows:

```
app\app.py = main application

app\templates\ = (main HTML pages)
   \_____ app\templates\includes\ = (footer, header and other complimentary HTML content)

app\static\ = css, js, fonts etc. 
   \____static\assets
   \____static\assets\fonts
   \____static\assets\images
   \____static\assets\static
   \____static\assets\static\fonts
   \____static\assets\static\images
   \____static\assets\static\fonts\icons
   \____static\assets\static\fonts\icons\fontawesome
   \____static\assets\static\fonts\icons\themify
   \____static\assets\static\images\datatables
```

Answer (score 0):

This was found to be a specific issue in the Adminator dashboard template for Python Flask. There are references in the bundle.js to these .woff and .eot fonts, and as there was no leading forward slash, the path/url wasn't being generated properly.

Fixed by changing any references like:

```
147: function (t, i, a) {
  t.exports =
    a.p + "static/assets/fonts/2c454669bdf3aebf32a1bd8ac1e0d2d6.eot";
},
```

To (note starting with '/')

```
147: function (t, i, a) {
  t.exports =
    a.p + "/static/assets/fonts/2c454669bdf3aebf32a1bd8ac1e0d2d6.eot";
},
```